# Wordpress portfolio: show only child categories

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a WP website with a portfolio section.
On portfolio page it shows project categories.
I would like to show only child categories of parent category with id=63.

This is the current code:

```
    <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'portfolio_category', 'string' ); ?>
    <?php $num_of_terms = count($terms); ?>

            <?php if($terms) { ?>   
            <div class="meta-column">
                    <strong class="caps"><?php esc_html_e( 'Artist', 'onioneye' ); ?><span class="colon">:</span></strong>
                    <span>
                        <?php 
                            $i = 0;

                            foreach($terms as $term) {

                                if($i + 1 == $num_of_terms) {
                                    echo esc_html($term -> name);
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo esc_html($term -> name . ', ');
                                }

                                $i++;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </span>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
$args = array('child_of' => 63);
$terms = get_categories( $args );
```

in place of this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'portfolio_category', 'string' );
```